# Python: Connect 4 with TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Alrighty I'm trying to implement a GUI for a game of Connect Four by using TKinter. Now I have the grid and everything set up what I'm having trouble with is getting the chip to show up on the board.

Here is my output: [image]

What I'm trying to do is make it so when I click one of the bottom column buttons a chip appears (and since this is connect four it should go from bottom to top)

Here is my code:

```
    from Tkinter import *
from connectfour import *
from minimax import *
from player import *
import tkMessageBox

class ConnectFourGUI:
    def DrawGrid(self):
        for i in range(0,self.cols+1):
         self.c.create_line((i+1)*self.mag,self.mag,\
                            (i+1)*self.mag,(self.rows+1)*self.mag)
        for i in range(0,self.rows+1):
         self.c.create_line(self.mag,(i+1)*self.mag,\
                            self.mag*(1+self.cols),(i+1)*self.mag)


    def __init__(self,wdw):

      wdw.title("Connect Four")
      self.mag = 60   
      self.rows = 6   
      self.cols = 7   

      self.c = Canvas(wdw,\
         width=self.mag*self.cols+2*self.mag,\
         height = self.mag*self.rows+2*self.mag,\
         bg='white')
      self.c.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=2)
      rlabel=Label(root, text="Player1:")
      rlabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

      self.player1_type=StringVar(root)
      options= ["Human", "Random", "Minimax"]
      self.player1_type.set(options[2])
      self.rowbox=OptionMenu(root, self.player1_type, *options)
      self.rowbox.grid(row=0, column=1)

      rlabel2=Label(root, text="Player2:")
      rlabel2.grid(row=0,column=2)

      self.player2_type=StringVar(root)
      self.player2_type.set(options[0])
      self.rowbox=OptionMenu(root, self.player2_type, *options)
      self.rowbox.grid(row=0, column=3)

      begin=Button(root, text="Start", command=self.game_start)
      begin.grid(row=0, column=4)
      self.c.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=7)

      play_col=[]
      for i in range(self.cols):
          play_col.append(Button(root, text= "Col %d" %i, command=lambda col= i: self.human_play(col)))
          play_col[i].grid(row=10,column="%d"%i)

##      self.DrawCircle(1,1,1)
##      self.DrawCircle(2,2,1)
##      self.DrawCircle(5,3,2)

      self.DrawGrid()
      self.brd = ConnectFour()


    def game_start(self):
        self.board=ConnectFour()
        print self.player1_type.get()
        print self.player2_type.get()
        if self.player1_type.get()=="Random":
            self.player1 = RandomPlayer(playernum=1)
            if self.player2_type.get()== "Random" or self.player2_type.get() == "Minimax":
                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Bad Choice", "You Have to choose At least 1 Human Player")
            else:
                self.player
        elif self.player1_type.get()=="Minimax":
            self.player1=MinimaxPlayer(playernum=2, ply_depth=4, utility=SimpleUtility(5,1))
            if self.player2_type.get()== "Random" or self.player2_type.get() == "Minimax":
                tkMessageBox.showinfo("Bad Choice", "You Have to choose At least 1 Human Player")
        elif self.player1_type.get()=="Human":
            self.player1=Human(playernum=1)
        if self.player2_type.get()=="Human":
            self.player2=Human(playernum=2)
        elif self.player2_type.get()=="Random":
            self.player2=RandomPlayer(playernum=2)
        elif self.player2_type.get()=="Minimax":
            self.player2=MinimaxPlayer(playernum=2, ply_depth=4, utility=SimpleUitlity(5,1))

        #self.currentplayer==1
        #self.draw()

    def human_play(self, col):

        if self.player1_type.get()=="Human" and self.player2_type.get() =="Human":
            while True:
                self.DrawCircle(row,col,1)
                if self.brd.is_game_over() is None:
                    self.DrawCircle(row,col,2)
                    if self.brd.is_game_over() is None:
                        pass
                    else:
                        print "Player 2 wins!"
                        break
                else:
                    print "Player 1 wins!"
                    break



    def DrawCircle(self,row,col,player_num):
        if player_num == 1:
            fill_color = 'red'
        elif player_num == 2:
            fill_color = 'black'
        #(startx, starty, endx, endy)
        self.c.create_oval(col*self.mag,row*self.mag,(col+1)*self.mag,(row+1)*self.mag,fill=fill_color)






root=Tk()
ConnectFourGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I know I'm supposed to call the DrawCircle function in the Human Play function, I'm just unsure as to how I'm supposed to set it all up. any advice as to how I could go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is depending on a few packages I don't have, so I can't be more specific, but the way I'd go about doing something like this is to track the X and Y coords of the chip works out the the row and column that it'd go into in the widget.

You'll need to create a location object, a tuple maybe, and then a way to translate the location object into a  drawable location. Then it's just a matter of incrementing either X or Y and detecting if there's a chip below it.